# How to write query NoSQL MongoDB in Studio 3T (robo 3T)?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, studio3t

I've never used Studio 3T application to access MongoDB NoSQL database. I'm not very familiar with this application. My question is, how do I write a query in the Studio 3T application to display some data, in case based on customer_id with a range for example 10 to 100 ? I'm install Studio 3T on ubuntu 22.04. May anybody can help me. Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to write this query without the app, just using the mongodb shell (for example)?

Comment: Yes I know, but this app is require for me. I can't see how to write the query in this app.